# how to get compiled cs file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In the webform world, when I set the debug flag by 
`<% Page Language="C#" Debug="true">`.

This used to give me ability to look into the compiled .cs code. I want to do the same with MVC. I can locate and see the compiled dll, however, I don't see any .cs file. I have set the Debug=true in the web.config. Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal that you cannot see any .cs file in an ASP.NET MVC view and there shouldn't be any. Views should contain only markup and no code at all. Code goes into controllers and models. ASP.NET MVC is just a different pattern than classic WebForms.

Comment: Oh that's not exactly true, for example views can and do contain code - loops for example to output the contents of a collection in the ViewBag, or ifs to render certain parts of a view depending on conditions in the model. Like it or not Views are code and they do get compiled.

Comment: @blowdart, no, loops are ugly. I would recommend you using editor/display templates which are more idiomatic way to do things in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Except display templates are simply partial views, and if you want to use them on collections you're just putting the loop inside the display template, which again gets compiled and again contains code.

Comment: @blowdart, it works by conventions. If you invoke a display template on a property which is of type IEnumerable this template will be automatically rendered for each element of the collection so that you don't have to worry about writing loops. It's done by the framework.

Comment: so i am kind of lost between your comments. Is there any class here or not? Just to be clear I am talking about the compiled class, meaning what is generated by ASP.NET runtime when you run your web application ( and not the regular cs file)

Comment: @imak, since ASP.NET MVC is based on the regular ASP.NET engine, views are dynamically compiled at runtime into an assembly.

Comment: In ASP.NET web form world, if you go to the temporary folder where those assimblies are compiled, you can also view the dynmically generated cs file. You have to have debug flag set in this case. My questions is how to view the same cs file in MVC world.